# Can i "Overvolt" a usb receiver to increase range for a Bluetooth device?

Tags: desktop-computer

Specifically a Logitech Wireless mouse.

**Model type:** Performance MX (darkfield)

**What i want to accomplish:**

overvolt the usb receiver by a little (fraction), similar to overclocking to increase the performance, sensitivity, more range, whichever you might call it.

Is this possible though the registry? can i overvolt the specific usb hub the receiver is plugged in?

Could you also tell me if this is a stupid idea to try?

> The kind of voltage increase i am interested in is like so: (.00001)
>   if you still know of a way (even though posted solution is here)
>   please comment, i would love to know.

**Reason:**

I have monitors in the pathway of the wireless mouse and receiver. I don't have the option of repositioning.

**Specs:**

*Windows 7, SP1, Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4440 CPU @ 3.10GHz*

Comment: I doubt this is possible and doubt that it would do you any good if it were possible. I see no reason to believe that increasing the voltage to a USB receiver would increase it's sensitivity. Overvolting in relation to overclocking is an entirely different situation.

Comment: What you see to forget is that Bluetooth, like Wi-Fi, is bi-directional. The two devices involved both have transmitters and receivers.

Comment: Increasing voltage probably will damage circuits before it does anything segnificant to the signal strength

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playing with the voltage you take a risk, even of shorting out the computer itself.
And I'm not at all sure that it is at all feasible, or even that this will help with the range problem.

The best solution is in my opinion to move the dongle nearer to the mouse,
which you can do using the [Logitech Receiver Extender](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00S38H5XG) ($12.50 on Amazon
with excellent reviews):

[image]

For more info see the article [Using the optional USB extender](http://support.logitech.fr/en_us/article/23120?product=a0qi00000069uzpAAA) :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this will have to do. Thank you for the research.